# Moving files from mint to arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-mint

I am new to using Linux systems. I am currently using Linux mint on a dual boot with Windows. I want to remove mint and switch to arch Linux but I also want to port over the files,folders and software if possible from mint to arch. so is it even possible to do that? any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: First, Arch is not a distro for new Linux users. It's probably best to learn with a more user-friendly distro like Linux Mint, then switch over to Arch. Your question shows that you are not ready. To answer your question, you can simply copy all the files you want to backup media, install Arch and restore the files from backup media. If you ask whether you can install Arch while keeping Mint files intact, that depends on your disk configuration. Assuming that Mint occupies a single partition and there is no more free space on the disk, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough for the files of yours, get a backup drive and copy the /home/user_name directory to it. Preferably the same file system as on the install most likely ext4. The programs well not sure how to get a list of them in the arch to see how they will match up but for the Mint before copying of the folder do this in the /home/user_name/ directory.

```
root@buster-raspi:~# dpkg --get-selections > selections.txt
root@buster-raspi:~# cat selections.txt 
adduser                     install
apache2                     install
apache2-bin                 install
snip...
xz-utils                    install
zlib1g:arm64                install
```

This will get the packages installed on your current machine for comparison for installing on the new. When you get your new machine installed it is possible to use the old home that you saved. Depending on the setup of the new OS and what it uses for the configuration methods if using some other default directories for instance the old install one will not work. But even then you mount your old directory on the new install and copy over the files wanted to the new install. So your options are use old directory on new install, hopefully compatible, backup the new first so you can go back to it if necessary. Or copying old directory files into place on new install. And of course checking for programs installed and installing them on the new, those distros are not compatible for binaries used it is not possbile to just copy them over.